# error when trying to insert values into MySQL table with python

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to insert this row of data (i parse from a list of tuples)

```
(0L, u'2012-11-06T16:23:36-05:00', 0L, None, 23759918L, u'baseline', u'0 to 100', nan, 105114L, 2009524L, True, u'charge', u'Charge')
```

into a mySQL database table, but i seem to have problems with the null value (NaN), because i receive this error:

```
OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'nan' in 'field list'")
```

I've tried making columns nullable in mySQL, and also making all text fields, but still no dice..

Comment: Do something else with the Not a Number float.

Comment: What are your column names in the table, and are you explicitly defining your column names in your insert statement?

Comment: yes, explicitly defining, im thinking of doing something like this :

Comment: for each tuple in my list set a NaN value to =MySQLdb.FIELD_TYPE.NULL

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `nan` is not a valid value for a `MySQL` column. It is complaining just about that. Your values string should be:

```
(0L, u'2012-11-06T16:23:36-05:00', 0L, None, 23759918L, u'baseline', u'0 to 100', null, 105114L, 2009524L, True, u'charge', u'Charge')
```

To achieve this, add some logic to your script to change all `nan` values to `NULL` string.